Reset addresses / remove attachment in Symfony Mailer
I am using Symfony 6.x in a project. I have to send emails in a command; and I have to execute this command multiple times. I've written another command to execute the 1st command in a loop, something like that:
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    ...

    foreach($params as $param) {
        $cmdParams = ['command' => 'my:first:command', 'arg1' => $param['arg1], 'arg2' => $param['arg2]];
        $cmdInput = new ArrayInput($cmdParams);
        $this->getApplication()->doRun($cmdInput, $output);
    }

    ...
}

In my first command, I have something like:
public function __construct(readonly MailerInterface $mailer)
{
    ...
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
{
    ...

    $email = (new Email())
    ->from(...)
    ->replyTo(...)
    ->addTo([...])
    ->addCc([...])
    ->addPart(...)
    ;

    $this->mailer->send($email);
    
    ...
}

Issue: Each mail sent carries the previous addresses (to, cc, etc) and attachments. I don't understand this behaviour.
Example:

1st mail sent

to: to-1@domain.tld
cc: cc-1@domain.tld
attachment: file-1.ext


2nd mail sent

to: to-1@domain.tld, to-2@domain.tld
cc: cc-1@domain.tld, cc-2@domain.tld
attachment: file-1.ext, file-2.ext
...


nth mail sent

to: to-1@domain.tld, to-2@domain.tld, ..., to-nth@domain.tld
cc: cc-1@domain.tld, cc-2@domain.tld, ..., cc-nth@domain.tld
attachment: file-1.ext, file-2.ext, ..., file-nth,ext



Should I reset the addresses / attachments? I can't figure out how to reset the To/Cc/Part. Any idea, please?
